# Understanding optional Transaction definition in Hibernate document

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, transactions

As per the [Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html), the definition for Transaction is:

> **Transaction** (org.hibernate.Transaction)
>
> (Optional) A single-threaded,
> short-lived object used by the application to specify atomic units of
> work. It abstracts the application from the underlying JDBC, JTA or
> CORBA transaction. A org.hibernate.Session might span several
> org.hibernate.Transactions in some cases. However, transaction
> demarcation, either using the underlying API or
> org.hibernate.Transaction, is never optional.

What it means when the doc says :

> However, transaction demarcation, either using the underlying API or
> org.hibernate.Transaction, is never optional.

Please help me in understanding what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Every database operation](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/) runs inside a transaction, even if you don't explicitly call begin/commit/rollback.

If you don't specify the database transaction boundaries then the AUTO-COMMIT mode is assumed. But while auto commit only makes sense from an SQL UI Browser, it doesn't make much sense for an ORM tool or even JDBC running more than one statements in one business method.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you need to use a transaction, whether it's through the annotation, or the normal API (i.e. start a `Transaction` with the session's `beginTransaction()` method and then commit it at the end).

Comment: Thanks Kayaman, when it says underlying API, then does it mean JDBC/JTA? please clarify.

Comment: Yeah, but I wouldn't mix too many different transaction implementations unnecessarily.